# Writing to a log file from a slim template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
rails 3.2
```

I am using slim as a template language.

Normally, in a Ruby file, I can use something like:

```
logger.info(params)
```

to get a dump of the params to the log file (when in development or test mode). Any idea what the syntax may be, for .slim to log debugging information to the log file?

Comment: This works for me in `slim`, are you getting an error or something?

Comment: What's the syntax? - logger.info()? I was getting errors

Comment: What errors? The exact syntax I used was `- logger.info(params.inspect)`

Comment: False alarm. I had a syntax error and was not deciphering the log properly. Inside the slim template, my editor does not add the closing "", so I forgot to add it manually

Comment: Ok, good you worked it out.